# how to access grandparent attribute in the child class with same name as some attribute in child class

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I was tinkering with classes and objects, then  I had a doubt, since all the non-private
methods and variables/attributes are available to the child class, and if there is any attribute in the parent class with the same name as some attribute in the child class, the it can be accessed using `super.attrName`. But what if this is the situation in case of multi-level-inheritence, and you want to access the grandparent attribute in the child class, how can it be done. using `super.super.attrName` gives error.

my sample code

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Abc sahil = new Abc();
        System.out.println(sahil.length);
    }
}

class A {
    int length;

    A() {
        this.length = 1;
    }
}

class Ab extends A {
    int length;
    
    Ab() {
        this.length = 2;
    }
}

class Abc extends Ab {
    int length;

    Abc() {
        this.length = 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write `super.super` in Java, that's why you are getting a compilation error.

The keyword `super` is used to get the attributes and methods from the immediate `parent` given that they are accessible from the `child`. So it expects only methods and attributes and not a keyword.

Now, if you want to access an attribute from the topmost parent, the best thing you can do is create an object and call the attribute. The other way of doing this is by creating a chain of methods in the intermediate parent classes. You can create a method in `Ab` that returns the `super.length` (A.length) and call that method from `Abc` using the `super` keyword. I won't recommend that because as the number of classes increases in the hierarchy you'll have to add this method in all the intermediate classes.

But, in a normal scenario, I've to ask a question. Consider the `Car` (a class) which has a `gasPedal` (an attribute), now there are `Audi`, `Bently`, and `Honda` which inherit from the `Car`. My question is that why would `Audi` be requiring the `gasPedal` from the `Car` when it has its own custom-designed `gasPedal`?

There is nothing wrong with accessing the superclass attribute, it is fine, but what I was trying to convey in the above question is a basic OOPs concept.

**Update regarding the comment**

When a person needs to have data regarding his grandparent's age, you'll need a new attribute in that person, `grandFatherAge`. Now this new attribute will be having the same value for every grandchildren he has, so you can declare it as `static`.

```
class GrandFather {
    
    int age = 88;
}

class Father extends GrandFather {
    
    int age = 50;
}

class Son1 extends Father {
    
    int age = 18;
    static int grandFatherAge;
    
    static {
        
        grandFatherAge = new GrandFather().age;
    }
}

class Son2 extends Father {
    
    int age = 15;
    static int grandFatherAge;
    
    static {
        
        grandFatherAge = new GrandFather().age;
    }
}

class Daughter1 extends Father {
    
    int age = 21;
    static int grandFatherAge;
    
    static {
        
        grandFatherAge = new GrandFather().age;
    }
}

class HierarchyManager {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println(Son1.grandFatherAge);
        System.out.println(Son2.grandFatherAge);
        System.out.println(Daughter1.grandFatherAge);
    }
}
```

I applied your "brainstorming" logic, a person can know his grandparent's age directly from his Grandparent, it is not necessary that it needs to come from his direct parent.

Comment: Sudhajaran i got what you said. one such scenario might be family hirerchy. where each human has age as an attribute, and somehow in some method inside the child, you need the grandparent's age. creating methods works, but what if the chain is really long, ins't there any way to relatively say get the age of the super of super (grandparent), which might not be the Base class in the chain of inheritence

Comment: just  brainstorming, it doesn't have to work

Comment: @SahilGautam, good point. You can check my updated answer.

Comment: A requirement that needs a.convoluted solution that is probably fragile would, imho, dictate rethinking the design

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your object to the class you're looking to reference.

The *[this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)* and *[super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)* keywords are essentially shortcuts; additionally, they can provide resolve for field names and local variable names.

```java
Abc sahil = new Abc();
System.out.println(((A) sahil).length);
System.out.println(((Ab) sahil).length);
System.out.println(sahil.length);
```

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: this does work, but isn't there any way to access them relative to the child class, say the parent of parent, without knowing the parent and grandparent class's names.

Comment: I see what you're saying, as you mentioned, _super.super.attrName_.  Not that I know of.  There may be a mechanism within the _reflection_ framework that can provide that type of resolve, although I'm not sure.  Additionally, you can research different hierarchical design patterns.  There may be a logic for creating that type of data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Child classes shadow the property of parent. If you cast the object to any of parent class the appropriate value be extracted.

```
System.out.println(sahil.length);  // 3
System.out.println(((Ab)sahil).length); // 2
System.out.println(((A)sahil).length); // 1
```